# Code Composer Studio - TI CC3200 Launchpad

Tags: code-composer

How can I upload the example "blinky" to the TI CC3200 Launchpad "firmware"?

I mean, I would like to plug in the board and the blinky example starts automatically on the startup of the board.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have to flash the flashmemory on the launchpad with a flashtool like [CCS UniFlash](http://www.ti.com/tool/uniflash).

Download CCS UniFlash. Once you're done with that, launch it and choose new target configuration. You will have an option on the left side that lets you choose the local url to your bin (or in this case, blinky bin file, which is typically in your SDK folder). Once you're done with that, you should be able to program it via the program button.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and complete method is to follow the procedure mentioned [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC31xx_%26_CC32xx_UniFlash_Quick_Start_Guide#CC32xx_MCU_image_flashing).

Note that you have to press on the file "/sys/mcuimg.bin" under "System Files", for the contents of the image displayed on the website to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add few lines on top of above answer.

1) When you build you project in CCS it will create .bin file in release folder of your project directory which you will flash in cc3200.

2) While doing so make sure cc3200 is in programmed mode.(SOP2 Jumper is on).

3) After you successfully flashed the .bin just remove the SOP2 and press reset.

Cheers !